# SQL Reporting Services - Multiple Snapshots?

Tags: reporting-services, snapshot

I have a report that has a snapshot generated weekly based on a default value for a location. Now I need to have that same snapshot run on the same report except with a different default value. Is there a way to do this without creating a new report with a slightly different default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Data-Driven Subscription with a Null Delivery Provider, and turn on caching.

Alternately, you can create a solution around the History snapshots, as in http://blogs.msdn.com/lukaszp/archive/2007/01/12/per-user-snapshots-or-multiple-snapshots-for-a-report-each-with-different-parameters-at-the-same-time.aspx